# Роутинг в yii2 после переноса на виртуальный хостинг

Tags: yii2, хостинг, роутинг

помогите пожалуйста в переносом проекта на шаред хостинг (в частности reg.ru)
в панели управления домен указана корневая папка вида:
/www/название.сайта и индексная страница как web/index.php
при заливке проекта на сервер везде добавляется в урлах web + ассеты (стили итп) по понятной причине не подгружаются тк он их не в папке имя/web/css.. ищет а в имя/css. думал поможет создание в /web файла htacess c такими данными:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

но увы..

Comment: версия basic или advanced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте в корень yii2 (basic), htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
//тут подключите все папки нужные: 
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*)$ web/fonts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ web/img/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

В папке web htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Также файл AppAsset.php (на всякий случай):

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
    //тут подключаете все нужные стили
        'css/main.css',
        'css/bootstrap-grid-3.3.1.min.css',
        'css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'css/slick.css',
        'css/slick-theme.css',
        'css/media.css',
        'css/fonts.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        //'js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js',
        'js/common.js',
        'js/slick.min.js',

    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset'
    ];
}
```

Comment: извините что не уточнил - basic

Comment: @user8494502 указал для basic

Comment: все равно бьет 500ю ошибку..

Comment: @user8494502 чтобы не гадать на кофейной гуще - надо смотреть в логи

Comment: еррор лог вот что пишет при обращении:
[Thu Nov 16 12:21:04 2017] [alert] [client 178.172.250.2] /var/www/u0247007/data/www/имя сайта/.htaccess: Invalid command '//\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd1\x82', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: @user8494502 а папка www точно та? я смотрю у вас их аж 3

Comment: странная ерунда. откуда там такое.на всякий случай дропнул домен из панели рег-а а создал заново и указал пути все теже (к индексу и к корневой директории), теперь этой ошибки в еррор логе нет,но ко всем урлам все равно дописывает web

Comment: @user8494502 в папке config -> web.php -> urlManager: 'enablePrettyUrl' => true,   'showScriptName' => false,

Comment: так и стоит. (я проект до этого делал на хецнере на впс и все ок было)
заметил что именно в генерации урл такая фигня. создается урл http://имя.ru/web/category/index а при переходе руками по http://имя.ru/category/index все ок.

Comment: @user8494502 'baseUrl' => '' вы установили?

Comment: установил - теперь все стало ок! вопрос (для просвещения) тогда если можно в 2х словах- почему нужно было его задать пустым?

Comment: @user8494502  по дефолту там стоит site.ru/web/index.php, вы переопределяете его и папка web исчезает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68806/discussion-between-user8494502-and-artem55555p).